# Model Binding property with implicit conversion from string to type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, modelbinders

I have the following class:

```
public class PostCode {
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator PostCode(string postCode)
    {
        return new PostCode {Name = postCode};
    }
}
```

It forms part of an `Address` class which is the model for a helper template (EditorTemplates>Address.ascx).

This helper template is rendered using `<%= Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address)%>` where `Address` is the property on another object.

Everything in the address is correctly bound when posting to the action method apart from the `PostCode` object. It seems likely that this is due to the fact that it is stored as a `PostCode` instead of a string.

How can I force the model binder to honour this cast?

Comment: can you show the helper template? in the receiving method of your post i'd add `FormCollection collection` to see how everything is coming in. probably the naming of your field is not exactly the same as your to be bound item in the form.

Comment: I've checked the AddKeys collection and the value is there on the Request object. It just doesn't make it onto the bound object.

Comment: What is the name of the object in the view and the AddKeys.  the default model binder will need an object named "Postcode.Name"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a string to represent the postcode in the ViewModel and did the conversion in the mapping to my domain entity.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have EditorTemplate for PostCode?
If not create it.